# Rails 3 vs Rails 2 "wild controller" routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm trying to get my Rails 3 project to automatically resolve namespaced controllers, similar to the Rails 2 behaviour. For example (Rails 2):

```
$ rails pathtest && cd pathtest
$ script/generate controller First
$ script/generate controller first/second
$ script/generate controller first/second/third
$ script/server
```

Requests to:

**/first** routes to first controller

**/first/second** routes to second controller

**/first/second/third** routes to third controller

But, Rails 3 yields different routing using the 'wild controllers' path.

```
$ rails new pathtest && cd pathtest
$ rails generate controller First
$ rails generate controller first/second
$ rails generate controller first/second/third

## config/routes.rb
Pathtest::Application.routes.draw do
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end

$ rails server
```

Requests to:

**/first** routes to first controller

**/first/second** routes to first#second

**/first/second/third** routes to first#second :id => 'third'

I'm starting to think that kind of automatic resolution of namespaced controllers isn't the way anymore? Has anyone found a way to automatically resolve namespaced controllers like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Pathtest::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :first do
    resources :second do
      resources :third
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, more details. I'm trying to get this done without listing all the controllers in the routes.rb - there are many (close to 100) controllers which are routed to.